# Position a image responsive

Tags: html, css

[the palm tree need to be width responsive](http://prntscr.com/mwpapg)

Hey, guys, I have a question.
On the website, I'm creating the designer asked me if I could make the palm tree responsive

```
position: absolute;
top: -100px;
```

doing it like this now... every px need a media query but that's impossible.
Could someone help me out with this? Is there a better solution?

Thanks for helping me out folks

Comment: The image you're linking to is not a palm tree. And if you want to make an image responsive, I'd suggest using percentages instead of pixels.

Comment: Hello Maarten, please remember that a screenshot is not enough for a question, a link, a code of HTML and CSS (as per your tags) might give us a better understanding of your problem. As now there could be a gazillion things going on. Please see [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dan kunnen we je verder helpen!

Comment: @Jake in the image there is a palm tree in it

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would make an image responsive by putting it within a parent  with width set to be a % value, then set the max-width of the image to be 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You can use % values or [view port](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem i did it with some media querys and position relative.
I did forgot that relative would not disable the height of the element.
So its responsive now :)